# make table fit into the page of my IEEE paper and minimize space

Tags: tables, paper

My table currently looks like this in my paper, it does not fit into  the page of my IEEE paper. A lot of space is wasted in the given format of this paper.

How can I make it fit into the the page of my IEEE paper's page? Here is the code I am using, I want the right part of the table to fit into the page

```
 \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}


 \begin{document}




\begin{table*}[]
 \caption{Matrix for Requirement-to-Code Validation/Auto-Completion}
  \label{tab:matrix}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{7}{l|} 
  {Callees/CallersCallers/CalleesCallees} \\ \cline{3-9} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & T & N & U & NT & UT & UN & UNT \\ \hline
  \multirow{21}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Callers/\\ Callers/\\ 
   Callees\end{tabular}} & \multirow{3}{*}{T} & \multirow{3}{*}{T} & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/ULeaf/Troot} & \multirow{3} 
    {*}{T} & \multirow{3}{*}{T} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{T} \\
     &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
     & \multirow{3}{*}{N} & \multirow{3}{*}{Uinner/Uleaf/Nroot} & 
      \multirow{3}{*}{N} & \multirow{3}{*}{Ninner/Uleaf/Nroot} & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{Uinner/Nleaf/Nroot} & \multirow{3}{*} 
    {Uinner/Uleaf/Nroot} & \multirow{3}{*}{N} & \multirow{3}{*} 
     {Uinner/Uleaf/Nroot} \\
      &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
        & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{Uinner/Tleaf/Uroot} & 
     \multirow{3}{*}{Ninner/Nleaf/Uroot} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3} 
     {*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} 
   \\
     &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
       & \multirow{3}{*}{NT} & \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/Tleaf/Uroot} & 
   \multirow{3}{*}{Ninner/Uleaf/Uroot} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3} 
     {*}{Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot} & \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot} & 
     \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot} \\
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
      & \multirow{3}{*}{UT} & \multirow{3}{*}{T} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & 
        \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/Uleaf/Troot} & \multirow{3}{*} 
  {Tinner/Uleaf/Troot} & \multirow{3}{*}{T} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & 
     \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/Uleaf/Troot} \\
   &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
    & \multirow{3}{*}{UN} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*} 
     {Ninner/Nleaf/Uroot} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & 
   \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{Uinner/Nleaf/Nroot} & \multirow{3} 
    {*}{U} \\
     &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{2-9} 
     & \multirow{3}{*}{UNT} & \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/Tleaf/Uroot} & 
     \multirow{3}{*}{Ninner/Uleaf/Uroot} & \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3} 
     {*}{Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot} & \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot} & 
      \multirow{3}{*}{U} & \multirow{3}{*}{Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot} \\
      &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fit the column width or fit text width?

Comment: the right part of the table should appear on the page which is not the case since the right part of the table is cut

Comment: Is it a two-column paper, as I understand it?

Comment: yes it is a 2 column paper

Comment: You can reduce the font size and the tabcolsep.

Comment: I prefer a solution that keeps the size constant

Comment: Use the  `table*` environment, the table will appear at the top of the following page.

Comment: I want it to occupy specifically only 1 column

Comment: With 9 columns? Split your table in two and write one above the other.

Comment: I just followed your advice and I used table* but my table is still overflowing and there is a lot of wasted space that I would like to minimize

Comment: You may try to set it sidewise. But your request is impossible. It is not possible to squeeze the table in one column without reducing its width. Still, with 6pt font size and 2 pt column separator, the table will not fit in one column. You can then try to reduce its height by reducing font size and arraystretch, and set it turned 90 degrees anticlockwise.

Comment: could you please post the solution as I am a little confused

Comment: Please try to clean up your table code. I highly doubt, that all the occurences or `\multicolumn{1}{c|}` are really needed. Also, whyt't the purpose of `\multirow{3}{*}`?

Comment: I removed them all

Comment: can you please show me the modified code that would make it fit into the page, I simplified the code as much as I could

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the main table setup from `tabular` to `tabularx`, to assure that the seven data columns have equal widths. I also chose to remove a lot of the nightmarishly complex wrapper code which you applied to virtually all cells and which does nothing except inhibit the proper working of the `tabularx` code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}
\usepackage{graphicx,textcomp,xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begingroup%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
    \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt
\scriptsize 
\caption{Matrix for Requirement-to-Code Validation/Auto-Completion}
\label{tab:matrix}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|c|*{7}{C|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{Callees/Callers Callers/Callees Callees} \\ 
\cline{3-9} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & T & N & U & NT & UT & UN & UNT \\ 
\hline
\multirow{7}{*}{\mytab{Callers/ \\ Callers/ \\ Callees}}
& T & T & U & Tinner/ULeaf/Troot & T & T & U & T \\ 
\cline{2-9} 
& N & Uinner/Uleaf/Nroot & N & Ninner/Uleaf/Nroot & Uinner/Nleaf/Nroot
& Uinner/Uleaf/Nroot & N & Uinner/Uleaf/Nroot \\ 
\cline{2-9} 
& U & Uinner/Tleaf/Uroot & Ninner/Nleaf/Uroot & U  & U & U & U & U  \\ 
\cline{2-9} 
& NT & Tinner/Tleaf/Uroot & Ninner/Uleaf/Uroot & U & Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot & Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot & U & Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot \\ 
\cline{2-9} 
& UT & T & U & Tinner/Uleaf/Troot & Tinner/Uleaf/Troot & T & U & Tinner/Uleaf/Troot \\  
\cline{2-9} 
& UN & U & Ninner/Nleaf/Uroot & U & U & U & Uinner/Nleaf/Nroot & U \\ 
\cline{2-9} 
& UNT & Tinner/Tleaf/Uroot & Ninner/Uleaf/Uroot & U & Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot & Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot & U & Tinner/Uleaf/Uroot \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the border of the table is overflowing on the right, this happens for the horizontal borders

Comment: @user3406764 - The code I posted above does not produce an overflow. If what you're running on your system does, then it must be because your code differs in substance from mine. As I'm not blessed with any particular psychic powers, I'm afraid I can't speculate meaningfully on how the code you employ differs from mine.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this layout, simplifying the code and using `\makecell`,which allows for multiline cells with the standard column specifiers:

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
     \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
     \usepackage{showframe}

    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
     \usepackage{algorithmic}
       \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}

    \newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
    \newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
     \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

     \begin{document}

    \begin{table*}
    \setcellgapes{1.5ex}\makegapedcells
    \centering
     \caption{Matrix for Requirement-to-Code Validation/Auto-Completion}
     \label{tab:matrix}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*{8}{c|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{7}{l}
      {Callees/CallersCallers/CalleesCallees} \\ \cline{3-9}
     \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & T & N & U & NT & UT & UN & UNT \\ \hline
    \multirowcell{20.2}{Callers/\\ Callers/\\ Callees} & T & T & U & \makecell{Tinner/ULeaf/\\ Troot} & T & T & U & T \\ %
    \cline{2-9}
      & N & \makecell{Uinner/Uleaf/\\ Nroot} & N & \makecell{Ninner/Uleaf/\\ Nroot} & \makecell{Uinner/Nleaf/\\ Nroot} & \makecell{Uinner/Uleaf/\\ Nroot} & N & \makecell{Uinner/Uleaf/\\ Nroot} \\ %
      \cline{2-9}
       & U & \makecell{Uinner/Tleaf/\\ Uroot} & \makecell{Ninner/Nleaf/\\ Uroot} & U & U & U & U & U \\%
        \cline{2-9}
    & NT & \makecell{Tinner/Tleaf/\\ Uroot} & \makecell{Ninner/Uleaf/\\ Uroot} & U & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\ Uroot} & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\ Uroot} & U & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\ Uroot} \\ %
       \cline{2-9}
         & UT & T & U & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\T root} & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\ Troot} & T &
        U & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\ Troot} \\ %
        \cline{2-9}
         & UN & U & \makecell{Ninner/Nleaf/\\ Uroot} & U & U & U & \makecell{Uinner/Nleaf/\\ Nroot} & U \\ %
         \cline{2-9}
       & UNT & \makecell{Tinner/Tleaf/\\ Uroot} & \makecell{Ninner/Uleaf/\\ Uroot} & U & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\ Uroot} & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\ Uroot} & U & \makecell{Tinner/Uleaf/\\ Uroot} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}

    \lipsum[1-15]

     \end{document}
```

[image]